# What should be FlutterRunArguments entrypoint?

Tags: android, flutter

We are using native views in our old flutter application but not using PlatformView because the code is from Flutter beta, showing native view by adjusting flutter view height in both iOS and Android using MethodChannel.

While configuring FlutterView in android, I was using following code,

```
    flutterView.runFromBundle(FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath(getApplicationContext()), null);
```

But as per the latest version of flutter we have to use `FlutterRunArguments`, like following code,

```
    FlutterRunArguments argsFlutter = new FlutterRunArguments();
    argsFlutter.bundlePath =  FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath();

    flutterView.runFromBundle(argsFlutter);
```

but while compiling it gives an error saying entrypoint needed and displaying black screen.

What should be the entrypoint?

```
argsFlutter.entrypoint = ??
```

Answer (score 1):

After searching for some time now, I didn't got clear answer from internet. While nothing was working, started referred my Medium Blog [Add multiple targets in Flutter apps (VS Code & Android Studio)](https://medium.com/flutter-community/add-multiple-targets-in-flutter-apps-vs-code-android-studio-efe7e588e0cd) and I got the answer from there. The entrypoint is nothing but the main.dart file from flutter :).

Final code is:

```
    FlutterRunArguments argsFlutter = new FlutterRunArguments();
    argsFlutter.bundlePath =  FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath();
    argsFlutter.entrypoint = "main";

    flutterView.runFromBundle(argsFlutter); //runFromBundle(FlutterMain.findAppBundlePath(getApplicationContext()), null);
```

Answering my own question assuming it will help someone.